# HLS live streaming subtitle doesn't appear

Tags: video.js, http-live-streaming, webvtt

I was trying to add subtitles to my Live HLS stream using [this tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9aXv.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9aXv.png): http://hlsbook.net/how-to-add-subtitles-to-a-live-hls-stream/ , also read all the issues on internet but didn't succeed.

The issue is that streaming works , and browser gets the video segments and subtitle segments (webvtt), then Player starts the video , but doesn't show the subtitles (even if it is selected by default), there no errors in console.

here is my master manifest file :

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=SUBTITLES,GROUP-ID="subs",NAME="English",DEFAULT=YES,AUTOSELECT=YES,FORCED=NO,LANGUAGE="en",URI="subslist/subtitles.m3u8"


#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1118592,CODECS="mp4a.40.2, avc1.64001f",RESOLUTION=640x360,SUBTITLES="subs"
prog_index.m3u8
```

Video Playlist (prog_index.m3u8):

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:2
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:5
#EXTINF:5.0,
seg.ts
#EXTINF:5.0,
seg.ts
#EXTINF:5.0,
seg.ts
```

subtitles list (subtitles.m3u8) :

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:2
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:5
#EXTINF:5.0,
subtitleSeg1.webvtt
#EXTINF:5.0,
subtitleSeg2.webvtt
```

[snapshot of player](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9aXv.png)

[browser's network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlyH6.png)

Comment: Can you share the player link you made?

Comment: Thank you Haris ur Rehman ,  I didn't deploy it yet . But I am using the same player from https://videojs.github.io/http-streaming/ demo.